# Oracle - Inline Query gives missing right parenthesis error for my code

Tags: sql, oracle11g, inline, inner-query

I am getting missing right parenthesis error on executing the below inline query in oracle:

```
" select * from ( "+
    " SELECT P.SZ_PARAM_CODE id, P.SZ_PARAM_DESC cap "+
    " FROM prm_vew_parameter P, PRM_PARAMETER_AVAIBILITY A, RULE_PARAMETER_ASSOCIATION X "+
    " WHERE P.SZ_PARAM_CODE=A.SZ_PARAM_CODE "+
    " AND A.SZ_PROG_SERVICE_CODE='RULE_PARAMS' "+
    " AND P.SZ_ORGID=X.ORGID "+
    " AND P.SZ_PARAM_CODE=X.PARAMCD "+
    " AND X.RULECD='ND_APTDEV' "+
    "  --AND   X.ORGID='' "+
    " AND   X.INOUT='I' "+           
    " UNION "+
    " select T.PARAMCD id, L.SZDESCRIPTION cap "+
    " from RULE_PARAMETER_ASSOCIATION t, CMN_VEW_CENTRAL_LOOKUP L "+
    " WHERE T.PARAMCD=L.SZCODE " +
    " AND   L.SZLOOKUPEFINEDFOR='L_RSK_OUTPUT_PARAM' "+
    " AND    L.SZ_ORGID=T.ORGID "+
    " AND   T.RULECD='ND_APTDEV' "+
    " AND   T.INOUT='O' "+
    " --AND   T.ORGID=':ORGID:' "+
    " AND   L.SZAPP_ID='RISK' "+
    " AND   L.SZGROUP_ID='Rule_type' "+          
    " UNION "+
    " SELECT T.SZ_TEMPPARAM_CODE id, T.SZ_TEMPPARAM_CODE cap "+
    " from RLMGR_M_RULE_TEMPPARAM T "+
    " WHERE T.SZ_RULESET_CODE='RULE_PARAMS' "+          
    " --AND   T.SZ_ORGID=':ORGID:' "+
    " ORDER BY cap )"+" where rownum <= 1 ";
```

Any help / suggestions on this will be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `--AND` -> `-- AND`

Comment: @10086 thanks, it did work for me.

Comment: It is weird it could work, "--" as far as i know cancels all the line till the next CR or end of sentence, which in your case never actually happened, IMHO i think you should add a CR after each last "+" or remove the lines with "--"